# how force to override from feature branch to master branch instead of merge in GitLab?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab

Situtation:

In Subversion, I have develop branch (100 version) and I branch out 50th version and moved to prod.

During Gitlab migration, I migrated prod branch to master and develop to develop.

In GitLab, I would like to override develop to master. so, I can bring into the track.

How to achieve this scenario?

Branch Name: feature_account_creation

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not good to "force" push any changes to a repo.

Git is very light weight with branches, does not consume much disk space.
You can always create a new feature branch off of master and continue your development.

If you must use the same branch name and choose to "force" push, you can try below command.

`git push -f <remote> <branch>`

`<remote>` is usually origin and `<branch>` is your branch (feature_account_creation)

1. Checkout master `git checkout master`
2. `git push -f origin feature_account_creation`

Answer (score -1):

Little more description for 1st posted question:

Thanks for your response Mohan. Just want to give little bit more background.

I have master, develop and feature_account_branch. Master migrated production van branch and develop migrated from active working branc. Both are migrated separately.

Currently, same file have separate version in master and develop.feature branch cloned from develop and released to production. To make single track I try to override feature to master.

Is it makes sense?

Or is any other way I can do mohan .